# How to add Wordpress image thumbnail above the post title

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to edit the post page inside our theme and wanted to add the thumbnail image above the post title but it keeps placing the thumbnail at the end of the post title. Any help is appreciated.

```
    if (have_posts()) :
                echo "<h1>" . __('Valhalla Integration Blog','avia_framework') . "</h1>";
                echo "<ul>";
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                }

                    echo "<li><h4><a href='".get_permalink()."' rel='bookmark' title='". __('Permanent Link:','avia_framework')." ".the_title_attribute('echo=0')."'>".get_the_title()."</a></h4></li>";

                    endwhile;
                echo "</ul>";
                else:

                  echo "<h3>" . __('No Blog Posts found','avia_framework') . "</h3>";

                endif;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're echoing an `<img>` tag into a `<ul>` which is invalid HTML.  I modified it to echo the image inside the `<li>` which also contains your title.

```
if (have_posts()) :
echo "<h1>" . __('Valhalla Integration Blog','avia_framework') . "</h1>";
echo "<ul>";
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

    echo "<li>";

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }

    echo "<h4><a href='".get_permalink()."' rel='bookmark' title='". __('Permanent Link:','avia_framework')." ".the_title_attribute('echo=0')."'>".get_the_title()."</a></h4></li>";

    endwhile;
echo "</ul>";
else:

echo "<h3>" . __('No Blog Posts found','avia_framework') . "</h3>";

endif;
```